# Suggestions for MySQL table

Tags: mysql

```
students
-------
name
age
email
colA
colB
colC

teachers
-------
name
age
email
colD
colE

parents
-------
name
age
email
colF
colG
colH
colI
```

for the above design, should i just create one table with an additional column called `user_type` or create 3 tables?
There will be millions of data to insert. I m worried about the performance if I use just one table for them.
I need suggestions from mysql gurus out here.

please advise.
thanks.

Comment: you have a school with millions of students??? :-)  But in all seriousness, the answer is that there are many "right" answers here; it depends on how the data is going to be used. In general though, having multiple types similar of data in a single table is not a performance issue if its properly indexed, so if that's your criteria for wanting to split it into three tables, then don't worry about it.

Comment: the database i m creating is not related to school. this is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

If i were to design a table, I rather do it in two tables.

UserType

```
- TypeID (Primary Key)
- TypeDescription
```

User

```
- UserID (Primary Key)
- TypeID (Foreign Key)
- ColA (nullable)
- ColB (nullable)
- ColC (nullable)
- ColD (nullable)
- ColE (nullable)
- ColF (nullable)
- ColG (nullable)
- ColH (nullable)
- ColI (nullable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create one table of users, and a separate user type table, linked through a foreign key.  Performance of any half-decent DBMS will be fine and may actually be slightly worse inserting into 3 separate tables.  In addition, searching through those tables will have worse performance because you'll have to `union` them in your queries.

This design assumes that all users have the same metadata associated with them.  If different users are considered as different entities and therefore have different metadata, it would be more logical to have them stored in 3 different tables.  However, you could still opt to have them in one table with all the metadata columns for every user and performance would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a user **inheritance** structure that you want to model in a relational database. Check out the following articles on the different ways to do it:

1. [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (your first option: „one table“)
2. [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
3. [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) (your second option: „three tables, each containing the common attributes“)

There are lots of questions and answers on stackoverflow regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to avoid nullable columns when possible, so I would do it this way:

```
persons  (or people if you prefer)
-------
name
age
email


students
-------
person_id
colA
colB
colC

teachers
-------
person_id
colD
colE

parents
-------
person_id
colF
colG
colH
colI
```